# Select2 in dynamic element open error

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using `select2` and load ajax data into it.

The `select2` element is inside dynamically loaded html (dynamic tab in jQuery ui tabs).

There is a situation that I remove the dynamic html (remove the tab) by calling jQuery remove for the container div and might load it all over again later on.

At the first time everything works perfectly. From the second time and on when I open the select2 element I get an error from the select2 js.

I suspect that select2 might add some elements outside this html boundaries that later on cause some error but it's only a guess.

Do I need to do something special when I want to destroy select2 control (That will clean it completely as it never created)?

Answer (score 0):

The knockout custom binding provided by select2 author, Ivan calls destroy on the element dispose so it cleans the control properly. 
Although the error occured when I tried to open select2 control **the actual problem was other custom binding for jQuery UI dialog**.
It created a race between the binding and and the dialog creation.
At the end I passed the dialog id to the view model and opened it from the view model by direct jQuery call.
It's not the most beautiful solution but it works without a hastle.
I really hope it will save someone the hours I spent investigating it.